# Markerclustererplus touch 'click' not working after today's maps update

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps JavaScript API with markerclustererplus.  I need markerclustererplus for its `mouseover` handler.

After today's Maps update, `click` is not longer functioning properly for touch screen devices.  `click` works fine for laptop/desktops using a mouse/trackpad, but it is not longer working for touch screens.

I tried both the markerclustererplus libraries available, both are broken.

https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclustererplus
https://github.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus

I tried the standard markerclusterer library as well, and it doesn't seem to be working either.

https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer

Everything was working fine before today's Maps update.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

---

EDIT:

I am using Django 1.11.  On the frontend, I don't use any libraries apart from a bit of jQuery 3.2.1

There's not much to show with my code.  It's pretty standard.

```
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clusterOptions);

markerCluster.addListener('click', function(cluster) {
    markerClusterActivate(cluster);
});

function markerClusterActivate(cluster) {
    ... stuff that happens when cluster is clicked
}
```

Comment: What update are you talking about? Where is your code? What have you tried to debug?

Comment: Right... according to [this message](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify/cp9SiuHXkFc), 3.31 just became the official release, although it's not [in the release notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases) yet (thanks Google).

Comment: post code showing the issue

Comment: I have exactly the same issue since earlier today.  It appears only affecting vue/nuxt.js projects.  The demo from markerclustererplus works.

Comment: You should file bug in Github to let developers of Markerclusterer know about this issue in the latest experimental version of Maps JavaScript API: https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/issues

Answer (score 0):

So here is a workaround, you just roll back to google map **3.30**

For vue.js projects.
https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/blob/v0.8.1/API.md

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import * as VueGoogleMaps from '~/node_modules/vue2-google-maps'

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    v: 'GOOGLE_MAPS_VERSION',
    libraries: 'places' // Only if you need Autocomplete
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's a good temporary fix.  I just added `v=3&` between `js?` and `key=...` in my `<script>`.